# Setting up simple NAT with iptables - which of two solutions is correct?

Tags: linux, networking, router, iptables

I have to set up iptables rules that will change all outgoing packets source addresses to router's public IP address and redirect all incoming packets with destination port 80 to one of the machines where the web server is. This is assignment from uni and I already have answers for that but they are somewhat inconsistent. One set of answers comes from the book where that task comes from (so it really should be correct) and the other comes from the teacher. So, the book says that it should be done this way (eth0 is public interface with public IP and eth1 is interface connected to local network - [a picture for better refference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SElMf.jpg)):

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source IPX
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-
destination IP1:80
```

and my teacher thinks that these are the correct answers:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -i eth1 -j SNAT --to-source IPX
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p -o eth1 tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-\ 
destination IP1:80
```

As you can see, the difference is in the chosen interfaces. From what I understand, options `-i` and `-o` are to differentiate between Outgoing and Incoming "subinterfaces" on an single interface.

So, the first rule in my book's answer says that all packets that are meant to be sent via interface eth0 should have it's source IP changed to router's public IP. My teacher says that all packets that arrive on router's local interface should have their source address changed to routers public IP.

In the second rule, book says that all packets coming on input "subinterface" of eth0 destined for port 80 should have their destination address changed and my teacher says that all packets going out of eth1 should have their address changed.

Which set of answers is correct? To me they both look correct, they just approach the problem from different sides, but after some research I found that most guides on the internet follow book's approach and it's possible that my teacher could make a mistake, so I don't really know which one is truly correct.
I'd be really thankful for quick response because I have a test from this subject in two days.

Answer (score 2):

> So, the first rule in my book's answer says that all packets that are meant to be sent via interface eth0 should have it's source IP changed to router's public IP. My teacher says that all packets that arrive on router's local interface should have their source address changed to routers public IP.

For a simple two-interface router, neither is wrong.

But if the router had *several* "internal" interfaces (let's say eth1, eth2, eth3), the book's solution would be more correct. The teacher's solution would needlessly SNAT all *internal* traffic, that is, packets from one internal subnet to another.

> In the second rule, book says that all packets coming on input "subinterface" of eth0 destined for port 80 should have their destination address changed and my teacher says that all packets going out of eth1 should have their address changed.

If I remember correctly, the outgoing interface is *not yet decided* in the prerouting stage (hence the name "pre-routing"), so you cannot match on `-o` at all. So the teacher's rule would not even be accepted by iptables. But I'll have to test...

Secondly, again, if the router had multiple LANs, you would not want DNAT (port forwarding) to apply to internal traffic. (Imagine a host on eth2 trying to reach a HTTP server on eth1 – you wouldn't want the router to accidentally divert it elsewhere...) So if there is no `-i` check, there should be *at least* a `-d` destination address check to avoid this.